# can i make a window form(common controls) using code in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, drag

instead of dragging and dropping a common control in vb.net, is there a way to hard code it?
or is there a way for me to be able to view the codes where a dragged and dropped object has
been created? thank you so much!

Comment: try inheriting form ...

Comment: how can i do it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The auto-generated code is intentionally hidden in the VB.NET IDE.  But you can easily reveal it.  Click the "Show All Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window.  You'll now see the Form nodes in your project displayed with a triangle.  Click on it to reveal the Designer.vb file.  And double-click that to see the code.

Observe the changes in the InitializeComponent() method as you use the designer to add/remove/edit controls.  It isn't perfect code, the machine generated it, but it gives you a major leg-up on what kind of code you need to write to "hard-code".

Comment: i did, but i can't find the widgets that i've created. but thanks. :)

Comment: Hard to guess if you need a pair of glasses or stop making "widgets".